# Workflow conditions on a choice field type (Checkboxes (allow multiple selections)) in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, workflow

I want to check the value of a choice column type that allows multiple selections. Basically;

```
If Current Item: Sports equals Hockey
  Do something.....
If Current Item: Sports equals Baseball
  Do something.....
If Current Item: Sports equals Football
  Do something.....
If Current Item: Sports equals Basketball
  Do something.....
```

Based on each item checked, when the condition is met the code execute for each item selected. I tried the obvious which looks just like the code I posted above.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question by experimenting a little more. If I have all options selected, Hockey, Baseball, Football, and Basketball, the Current Item value "Sports" will look like this

**String:**                      ;#Hockey;#Baseball;#Basketball;#Football;#
**Choices, comma delimitted:**   Hockey, Baseball, Football, Basketball

So if I write my workflow this way;

If Current Item: Sports contains Hockey
  Do something.....
If Current Item: Sports contains Baseball
  Do something.....
If Current Item: Sports contains Football
  Do something.....
If Current Item: Sports contains Basketball
  Do something.....

if the value is selected , I am able to search the "array" or list items and execute the condition based on if the option is contained  or not.

Thought I would post my answer in case it helps somebody else out. There are more complicated solutions online, but this one is simple and works well for me